# I don't undestand fetch JS code. I am working with pattern MVC. PHP

Tags: php

Need help with JS code. What to write in fetch request? I have a route.php which breaks the controller/action. I need to split the fetch request in the same way or make a direct link to controller_signup.php ? If I make a direct link to the file, it gives the error: "Class 'Controller' not found".

route.php

```
class Route
{
    static function start()
    {
        
        $controller_name = 'Main';
        $action_name = 'index';
        $routes = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        if ( !empty($routes[1]) )
        {   
            $controller_name = $routes[1];
        }
        if ( !empty($routes[2]) )
        {
            $action_name = $routes[2];
        }
        $model_name = 'Model_'.$controller_name;
        $controller_name = 'Controller_'.$controller_name;
        $action_name = 'action_'.$action_name;
}
}
```

Js

```
const form = document.getElementById('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', formSend);

async function formSend(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const data = new FormData(form);

    await fetch('signup/register', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data,
    });
}
```

controller_signup.php

```
class Controller_signup extends Controller
{

    public
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->model = new model_signup();
        $this->view = new View();
    }

    public function register(): bool
    {
        if (!empty($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
            $regLogin = $_POST['login'];
            $regEmail = $_POST['email'];
            $regPassword = md5($_POST['password']);
            $this->model->registerNewUser($regLogin, $regEmail, $regPassword);
            return true;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Unrelated: From PHP's [md5](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) manual: "_Warning It is not recommended to use this function to secure passwords, due to the fast nature of this hashing algorithm. See the [Password Hashing FAQ](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash) for details and best practices._"

Comment: @Manik, I getting "302 found" then 404.

Comment: In your controller, do you have a `namespace` and `use ...` or is the code you posted all you have?

Comment: @brombeer No, else I have files views, models and another controllers.